# Handle text overflow in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to manage input to Text widget below, when i am having a hardcoded value like "data" it works fine but when i pass variable which has input value i get overflow issue. I am able to understand why its giving error but not sure how to fix that.

```
 return Container(
      width: sizew,
      height: sizeh,
      decoration: boxDecoration,

      child: FlatButton(            
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),            
        onPressed: onTap,             
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(10,10),)
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(                                                
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[                                                                                               
              child  ?? Container(),
              Text("data"),                
            ],
          ),
        ),  

      ),          
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flexible widget like this

```
Flexible(
   child:
         Container(child:
                        Text("yourdata")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give property of `overflow` to the `Text` widgets as follows:

```
Text("data", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
```

There are plenty of others which you can try, have a look at these and chose which suits your requirements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what i was doing wrong, but i just realized that

```
Text(label)
```

Is not accepted by flutter, even though other values like sizew and sizeh works direct. Passing value like, solved my problem. As there was error related to overflow i was trying to solve it different way. I should have mentioned how i am passing value in my post to make it clear...

```
Text('$label')
```